# Unable to commit to git repo. Pathspec 'origin' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm working off of an existing project that I have been committing and pushing to git. For a couple reasons, I had to change rails versions from 4.0 to 3.2.6 and use existing project files from a tutorial by downloading the files and replacing my local app folder with them.

Now I can't push to my existing repo on git that I have been working on.

If I try to commit, I get two errors:

error: pathspec 'origin' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I tried to delete the local app folder, clone the repo and then replace all of the files with the 3.2.6 version app that I have been working on but I still get the same commit errors.

Comment: did you do some change to .git folder?
try git branch , and check whether the master exist? can you do this and post what you get?

Comment: you saying that you have cloned repo originally from the source and replaced the files manually and you still get the same problem? ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify the full git push command:

```
git pull -u origin master
```

If it doesn't work, check if your remote declaration were altered in any way:

```
git remote -v
```

also, as show [in this article](https://coderwall.com/p/zcozuq), list references and branches:

```
git branch -avvv
git show-ref
```

check that you are in a branch, and not in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

Make sure you don't have a branch named '`origin`' (which would be confusing here)

---

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/41) (for git svn, which isn't your case, but can still give interesting idea), trying to clone again the repo could lead to a non-corrupted `.git` folder, and the ability to push again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your git config file placed in

```
.git/config
```

in your project folder? You can find the details of your repo & branches information in this file.

Hope it helps.